# Menu's and breadcrumb for a node with different parents in drupal

Tags: drupal, menu, view, taxonomy, breadcrumbs

I am having a problem using Drupal 6. I have page node that includes a block (this block does some custom xml processing, etc). I'm referencing this node in other menu's but the breadcrumbs don't end up being correct, and neither are the menu's. The menu's seem to be all merged.

It is possible to see it in action here:
staging.katimavik.org, clicking on about us at the top, then on the left menu of the content area, clicking on community and work partners.
Then if you Hover over "I am" and click on A Youth, and in the content area, left menu click on "Where in Canada", you will notice the breadcrumbs not correct, and neither are the menu's.

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I have read a little about taxonomy and views but don't know where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally change your breadcrumbs in your theme's template.php. See an example at http://thedrupalblog.com/manually-replace-link-breadcrumbs